# Show that $\phi$ is equal to a linear function almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi$ be a function in $L^2[0,1]$ such that, for every continuous function $\psi$ on $[0,1]$ such that the equalities

$$\int_0^1 \psi(x)dx = 0 \hspace{.5cm} \text{and} \hspace{.5cm} \int_0^1 x \psi(x)dx = 0$$
hold, the equality $\int_0^1 \phi(x)\psi(x)dx = 0$ also holds.

I want to show that $\phi$ is a linear function almost everywhere.

I understand that $\int_0^1 (ax+b)\psi(x)dx = 0$, but how do I show that $\phi$ must be of the form $ax+b$ almost everywhere?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: It is nice when people take the time to write well written posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L^{2}[0,1]$ is a Hilbert space. In any Hilbert space $M^{\perp \perp} =M$ if $M$ is a closed subspace. Take $M$ to be the subspace of $L^{2}[0,1]$ spanned by $1$ and $x$. The hypothesis says that $\phi$ is orthogonal to $\psi$ if $\psi$ is orthogonal to   $1$ and $x$. Hence $\phi \in M^{\perp \perp} =M$ and $\phi$ is a linear combination of $1$ and $x$.